# Hierarchical Version of Bayesian Change Detection Model in JAGS

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, jags, change-point

I am trying to create a hierarchical changepoint detection model in JAGS, estimating group difference in changepoint based on individual changepoints in scores for an outcome variable (fictional in this case). I can run a non-hierarchical version of this same analysis, based on a single set of scores, but am having trouble thinking through the hierarchical structure in `JAGS`.

Here is code for creating the toy data. `score` is a fictional outcome variable measured on each of 84 `days` for forty individuals (variable `id`) divided equally among two groups (variable `group`). Data is created so the individuals in group A tend to have a later breakpoint (around day 34) than those in group B (around day 15).

```
set.seed(1234)

breakpointG1 <- NA
for (i in 1:20) { breakpointG1[i] <- round(rnorm(1, 34, 5)) } 
breakpointG2 <- NA
for (i in 1:20) { breakpointG2[i] <- round(rnorm(1, 15, 5)) } 
bps <- c(breakpointG1, breakpointG2) 
group <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20)
df <- data.frame(id = NA, days = NA, group = NA, score = NA)
for ( i in 1:length(bps) ) {
pre <- rnorm(bps[i], 40, 3) # 
post <- rnorm(84-bps[i], 25, 3)
dfi <- data.frame(id = i, days = 1:84, group = rep(group[i], 84), score = c(pre, post))
df <- rbind(df, dfi)
}
df <- df[-1,]
```

Now plot all participants in one graph, but with a separate loess-smoothed line for each group.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = days, y = score)) + 
       geom_point(aes(colour = factor(id))) + 
       geom_smooth(aes(group = group, linetype = group), colour = "black", span = 0.5, se = F) + guides(colour = F)
```

[image]

The difference in group change thresholds is clearly visible on this graph. Now for the Bayesian analysis verifying what we can see with our eyes. First step is to create the data list from the dataframe.

```
y <- df$score
sdY <- sd(y)
mY <- mean(y)
g <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$group))
sid <- df$id
days <- df$days
nTotal <- nrow(df)
nDays <- max(df$days)
nID <- length(unique(sid))
nG <- length(unique(g))
```

We also need a vector where each element is the group number of the subject in question (i.e. there will be 40 elements in this vector)

```
groupOfSubject = NULL
for ( sIdx in 1:nID ) {
  groupOfSubject = c( groupOfSubject , unique(g[sid==sIdx]) )
}

dataList = list(y = y,
                sdY = sdY,
                days = days,
                sid = sid,
                nTotal = nTotal,
                nDays = nDays,
                nID = nID,
                nG = nG,
                groupOfSubject = groupOfSubject)
```

Now the model string for jags. The main things I am interested in estimating are the group changepoints `muChng[]` and the `muB[]`s for pre- and post-breakpoint `score`. I have used nested indexing but I must confess I am out of my depth here.

```
cat("
    model{
    
    # likelihood
    for (oIdx in 1:nTotal) {
    y[oIdx] ~ dnorm(mu[sid[oIdx]], 1/sigma^2)
    mu[sid[oIdx]] <- b1[sid[oIdx]] + step(days[oIdx] - chng[sid[oIdx]])*b2[sid[oIdx]]
    }
    
    # priors
        # on subject-level id for b
        for (sIdx in 1:nID) {
             b1[sIdx] ~ dnorm( muB1[groupOfSubject[sIdx]], 1/10^2 )
             b2[sIdx] ~ dnorm( muB2[groupOfSubject[sIdx]], 1/10^2 ) 
             chng[sIdx] ~ dnorm( muChng[groupOfSubject[sIdx]], 1/10^2 ) 
             }

            # prior on group  
            for (gIdx in 1:nG) {
                 muB1[gIdx] ~ dnorm(0, 1e-6)
                 muB2[gIdx] ~ dnorm(0, 1e-6)
                 muChng[gIdx] ~ dunif(1,nDays)
                 }
  
    # prior on Sigma
    sigma ~ dunif(1/sdY*10,sdY*10)

    }", file = "temp.jag")
```

Next adapt the mcmc chains using `rjags::jags.model()`.

```
library(rjags)
jagsModel <- jags.model(file = "temp.jag",
                        data = dataList,
                        n.chains = 3,
                        n.adapt = 1000)
```

But the model doesn't run

```
Error in jags.model(file = "temp.jag", data = dataList, n.chains = 3,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 7.
Attempt to redefine node mu[1]
```

I am not as familiar with breakpoint models as with the general linear model so am not sure where I am going wrong. Something to do with the nested indexing in the definition of `mu[]` in the likelihood function I think, but I can't see where, and none of the alternatives I have tried seem to work. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to John Kruschke for helping me with this. All the model above requires to run is to change the specification of the likelihood from  `mu[sid[oIdx]] <- b1[sid[oIdx]] + step(days[oIdx] - chng[sid[oIdx]])*b2[sid[oIdx]]` to `mu[oIdx] <- b1[sid[oIdx]] + step(days[oIdx] - chng[sid[oIdx]])*b2[sid[oIdx]]`. Plotting histograms of the mcmc chains for `muChng1` and `muChng2` reveal that the model has retrieved the higher-level group changepoints we programmed into the data very well.

The advantage of this model over a single-level model is that we can get estimates of changepoints for each individual as well as for each group.